# Jstree, get_checked, pass value to div onselect event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, checkbox, jstree

i'm using an MVC c# asp.net 4.0 project with Jstree, but i have a small problem i have a jstree that's populated witha a JSON array.

My problem is I need to catch the value of the checkboxes in jstree when checked to a div in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i finally got this working this is the solution i hope it Help's someone :)

first you must bind:

```
    .bind('check_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        $("#listSelectedActives").html(BuildList());
    })
   .bind('uncheck_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
       $("#listSelectedActives").html(BuildList());
```

then the use this function:

```
function BuildList() {
    var checked = $("#demoTree").jstree("get_checked", null, true);
    var output = "";

    $(checked).each(function (i, node) {
        var id = $(node).attr("ID");
        var text = $(node).attr("NodeText");


        output += "<p>ID: " + id + " TEXT: " + text + "</p>";
    })

    return output;
}
```

If this is too confusing please let'me know :)